# How to fix dataTables research

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables, but I have a problem. When I put more than  2characters, nothing is displayed.

```
    var table = $selector.find('table').DataTable({
          "bLengthChange": false,
          "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
        });
        $('.search-table tfoot th').each( function () {
          var title = $(this).text();
          $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        });
        table.columns().every( function () {
          var that = this;
          $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
              that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
            }
          });
```

If I remove this function its will work

```
           table.columns().every( function () {
              var that = this;
              $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                  that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
                }
              });
```

But I can't use the multi filter.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Just reading code... It looks like a `this` and `that` problem. Have you tried with `.search(that.value)`? If it don't work either... Can you post a codePen / Fiddle or a live link ?